# Display "list" columns on sharepoint as chips when previewing items as "thumbnails"

Tags: json, sharepoint

I have created a library on my Sharepoint to display .docx files (preview, title, and a custom field: my company's departments from a list).

To display the items correctly, I used a custom style with "format current view" and edited the .json but I have a problem because the basic "list" view displays the departments as "chips", like this :
[Example with chips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HjBy.png)

But in thumbnail mode, it's a simple string of characters separated by commas.
[Example of my render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJvO.png)

How can I display this list of departments as chips despite the thumbnail view?

Here's an example of what I'd like (I've photoshopped my two screen prints) :
[What i'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MPHH.png)

I tried to edit json but there is no loop, it's seem to be a string :

```json
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "attributes": {
                "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "p",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "[!Departments0.DisplayName]"
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "p",
                  "attributes": {
                    "title": "[$Departments0]",
                    "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-label "
                  },
                  "txtContent": "=if ([$Departments0] == '', '–', [$Departments0])"
                }
              ]
            }
```

Thank you.
Capu